# Receiving empty payload with recvfrom when using SOCK_DGRAM?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, recvfrom

Is it possible to receive any empty payload with [`recvfrom()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) with `SOCK_DGRAM` based socket? The server is only interested in the client header to send it back a message (i.e. single message, send only protocol).

Comment: Yes. You can send zero-length datagrams with UDP.

Comment: @EJP How? `recvfrom()` never blocks on zero-lengths, and attempting to send empty package using for example `cat /dev/null | nc -u 127.0.0.1 1234` with `recvfrom()` in busy waiting does nothing.

Comment: With `send()`, or `sendto()`, supplying a zero length parameter. `recvfrom()` will block until a datagram is received or an error occurs.

Comment: @EJP `recvfrom()` in my case never blocks and always returns zero.

Answer (score 0):

0-sized datagrams are perfectly valid from socket API perspective and at least protocols IP, UDP, UNIX: one can send and receive them.